# NestJs Swagger: How to define Api Property for dynamic classes

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, openapi, nestjs-swagger

I have below class

```
export class DocumentsSteps {
    @ApiProperty({type: ???})
    [type: string]: DocumentStep;
}
```

How should I define ApiProperty type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now (9/21/2021), this isn't possible with Nest's `@nestjs/swagger` library, due to the fact that there's no field to reflect metadata on. There may be an opportunity to [open a pull request](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger) to allow for the use of [dictionaries](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/) with the library, but right now your best bet would be modifying the swagger document that Nest generates and adding it on your own at the moment

Comment: would you please add a small sample here about the changes manually, what should it look like

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it with a function

```
export type Constructor<I> = new (...args: any[]) => I

function ErrorDto(statusCode: number, message: string): Constructor<Error>{
  class Error implements Error{
    @ApiProperty({ example: statusCode })
    readonly statusCode: number

    @ApiProperty({ example: message })
    readonly message: string

  }
  return Error
}
export class UnauthorizedErrorDto extends ErrorDto(401, 'Unauthorized'){}
export class BadRequestErrorDto extends ErrorDto(400, 'Bad Request'){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, it looks a little ugly on swagger but it's the best possible way.

Using additionalProperties, you can add dynamic keys, with a typed value by providing a reference to your Dto.
The Dto will not be a part of some other response and may not be available in swagger, to expose it, we need to use `@ApiExtaModels()`

```
@ApiExtraModels(DocumentStep)
export class DocumentsSteps {
    @ApiProperty({
        additionalProperties: { oneOf: [{ $ref: getSchemaPath(DocumentStep) }] },
    })
    [type: string]: DocumentStep;
}
```

The result looks like this
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check this out

https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#decorator-composition

You could implement another decorator to extends the ApiProperty

```
export function CustomApiProperty(type: string) {
  return applyDecorators(
    ApiProperty({type, ...}),
  );
}
```